# android calculator

Tags: android

i was designing a calculator similar to win 7 calc i have used colspan to make 0 button to size of two cols but i am not getting how to make = button to size of two rows i am using table layout..
i tried it with android:layout_span but its working only for colspan is ther any thing for row span

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >




    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="257dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="7" android:textSize="40dp"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="8" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="9" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="*" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="4" />

            </TableRow>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="5" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="6" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="/" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button10"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="%" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button11"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="1" />

            </TableRow>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button12"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="2" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button13"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="3" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button14"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="-" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button15"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="=" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:
            >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button16"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:text="0" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button17"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="." />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button18"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="+" />

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it in table view..So i suggest u to use ur last column outside of the table layout. And change the parent layout to Relative Layout.